# Connect Google cloud storage with Google app engine

Tags: codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

How can I connect My Codeigniter Project in Google App Engine with Google Cloud Storage?

Any ideas?

Comment: docs here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/

Comment: Can you give a bit more info on the specifics of what you are trying to do? See also: https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2014/01/15/php-app-engine-apps-and-file-system-concepts/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP Client Library [1]. Here you hace an example to upload a file to a bucket:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

/**
 * Upload a file.
 *
 * @param string $bucketName the name of your Google Cloud bucket.
 * @param string $objectName the name of the object.
 * @param string $source the path to the file to upload.
 *
 * @return Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface
 */
function upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $file = fopen($source, 'r');
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
        'name' => $objectName
    ]);
    printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php